# Optimal Networking Setup for a 2-Story unit?

Tags: networking

I am moving into a 4 bedroom two-story unit. It’s roughly 2,200 sq ft.

I want absolute max throughput possible to be achieved in all focal points. We’re all in internet related industries. Between gaming and web-development latency and throughput are major factors for us.

Here’s our main focal points:

1) Garage (office). downstairs

2) Each bedroom x4. upstairs

3) Living room. downstairs

The fastest line we can get is Comcast 50mbdown/5up (Wideband).

I am looking for the best way to achieve wireless and wired performance for our setup.

Our gaming computers may be in our bedroom, and we also may bring it down to the office every now and then for “LAN” sessions. Most wireless will be happening downstairs with our laptops, but since we may do LAN sessions then hard wired latency may be important there too.

My concerns: If we do only wireless there would be too much latency for gaming.

I don’t know if placing one D-link DGL 4500 on the top floor would be enough; which I currently own. (http://dlink.com/us/en/home-solutions/support/product/dgl-4500-xtreme-n-gaming-router)

As far as I’m aware wireless signals transfer best top down. Would this wireless router be enough on top floor and that’s it?

My second strategy was a combination of wiring and wireless but I’m not sure what’s easiest way to do this?

This is a place we’re renting, so I’m not sure how much leeway we have with wiring, but we’re all pretty competent... if we can’t drill through a wall we can probably “stitch” them across the edges wherever needed.

Thoughts on the optimal way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably use that router on the top floor and pick up another router with the capability of being a wireless repeater (A large assortment of current routers have this capability but you should double check), which would be placed in the Garage (office). This placement would do two things

1. Present wired hookups in the office where LAN would happen
2. Give more signal strength to the basement.

Comment: How does the repeater affect latency when working/gaming in the office/garage?

Comment: @user29336 I've never noticed such latency but if there is too much one could run an Ethernet line between the two routers (plugging the end from the original router into the Internet port on the repeating router) or use Ethernet routed through the main electricity.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest combining a wireless solution for convenience with a wired solution for times when you require it, if wiring is is going to be a significant problem then powerline (Ethernet over mains electricity) would probably present an easy and convenient middle ground solution. wireless is never going to be as good, but if u do decide on it ensure you use significantly different channels to avoid interference.
Other than that its hard to say what will and won't work in terms of your specific environment, by way of an example I'm sat five metres from a wireless N router and have awful signal cause of the concrete walls!